# Why won't CSSTransitionGroup work in my dropdown example?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

I'm having a heck of a time animating a simple dropdown using React CSSTransitionGroup.  I'd like to animate it sliding up and down.  I grabbed this code from an online example which was working, but it won't seem to work for me.  The menu just appears and disappears instantly.

FWIW, I'm testing this in react-storybook.  This is really my first test using it (so far, I like it), but I don't know if it may be interfering with something.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup';

class NavbarDropdownBase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        };

        this.onClickHeader = this.onClickHeader.bind(this);
    }

    onClickHeader(event) {
        this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
    }

    render() {
        let items, nodes;
        if (this.props.items && this.state.expanded) {
            if (this.props.items) {
                nodes = this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <a onClick={() => this.props.onItemClick(item)}>{item.label}</a>
                    </li>
                ));
            }

            items = (
                <div key="items" ref={c => this.items = c} className="items">
                    <ul>
                        {nodes}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            items = <div key="items" ref={c => this.items = c} className="items" />;
        }


        let className = 'navbar-dropdown';
        className += this.state.expanded ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
        className += (this.props.className || '');

        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <div className="header" onClick={this.onClickHeader}>
                    <h3>Click</h3>
                </div>
                <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="menu" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
                    {items}
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const NavbarDropdown = NavbarDropdownBase;`

export default NavbarDropdown;

NavbarDropdownBase.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onItemClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And here's my LESS:

```
.navbar-dropdown {
    .items {
        ul {
            list-style-position: inside;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    } 
}

.menu-enter {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-enter.menu-enter-active {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
}

.menu-leave {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.menu-leave.menu-leave-active {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup';

class NavbarDropdownBase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        };

        this.onClickHeader = this.onClickHeader.bind(this);
    }

    onClickHeader(event) {
        this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
    }

    render() {
        let items, nodes;
        if (this.props.items && this.state.expanded) {
            if (this.props.items) {
                nodes = this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <a onClick={() => this.props.onItemClick(item)}>{item.label}</a>
                    </li>
                ));
            }

            items = (
                <div key="items" ref={c => this.items = c} className="items">
                    <ul>
                        {nodes}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }


        let className = 'navbar-dropdown';
        className += this.state.expanded ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
        className += (this.props.className || '');

        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <div className="header" onClick={this.onClickHeader}>
                    <h3>Click</h3>
                </div>
                <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="default" 
                    transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                    {items}
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const NavbarDropdown = NavbarDropdownBase;

export default NavbarDropdown;

NavbarDropdownBase.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onItemClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And my LESS:

```
.navbar-dropdown {
    .items {
        ul {
            list-style-position: inside;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    } 

    .default-enter,
    .default-leave.default-leave-active {
        max-height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .default-leave,
    .default-enter.default-enter-active {
        max-height: 500px; /* Approximate max height of dropdown */
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .default-enter.default-enter-active,
    .default-leave.default-leave-active {
        transition: max-height .3s linear;
    }
}
```